# Laravel : How to create custom Register

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have 2 register and login form. The one is used to user and others is used to admin role.
In user role, I using from laravel authentication, is good and work well.
But, the problem is when I create custom register from admin role, its can't work well.
It can't store to database, when I check using `echo` function, it's not print anything just refresh the page.

Could you help me, what is wrong ???

- this is my route

  ```
  Route::get('/adminregister', 'Auth\LoginController@formreg')->name('admin-reg');
  ```
- this is my controller

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
    use App\User;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    
    class AregisterController extends Controller
    {
       
        use RegistersUsers;
       
        public function __construct()
        {
           // $this->middleware('guest');
        }
    
       
        public function create(Request $request)
        {
            
            $this->validate(request(),[
                'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
                'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            ]);
         
            if ($request('confirmpassword') == $request('password')){
                $user = User::create(request(['name','email' ,'password','is_admin' => True, ]));
              //  return redirect()->route('admin-login')->with('status', 'Successfully create account');;
            }
            else {
                
                return redirect()->route('admin-reg')->with('status', 'Confirm Password not match');;
            }
        }
    }
```

In this controller, fisrt I want to check the password will confirmation password then store it to database.

- this is my view page

```
<form action ="{{ route('user-create') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                                        <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
                                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                                    <div class="form-floating mb-2 mb-md-0">
                                                        <input class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" type="text" placeholder="Enter your first name" name="name" />
                                                        <label for="inputFirstName">Name </label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                                <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail" type="email" placeholder="name@example.com" name="email"/>
                                                <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <div class="form-floating mb-3 mb-md-0">
                                                        <input class="form-control" id="inputPassword" type="password" placeholder="Create a password" name="password" />
                                                        <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <div class="form-floating mb-3 mb-md-0">
                                                        <input class="form-control" id="inputPasswordConfirm" type="password" placeholder="Confirm password" name="confirmpassword" />
                                                        <label for="inputPasswordConfirm">Confirm Password</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="mt-4 mb-0">
                                                <div class="d-grid"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create account</button></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
```

Do you have any suggestion of how to fix it? It cant store anything in database, and when I check it using " echo " there is nothing :)
Thank you

Comment: `$request` isn't callable ... the `confirmed` rule is looking for a field named `password_confirmation` ... adding this to the array of inputs you want from the request isn't doing what you think `'is_admin' => True` ... you don't need to compare the 2 passwords as that is what the `confirmed` rule did already ... but in short validation is failing, after that isn't failing you will have PHP errors

Comment: @lagbox what should I do? I am newbie on laravels. Could you explain it step by step so it can running well ? , In this, I will add role to admin that is_admin is true, then I add this to array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `confirmed` rule is looking for a field name `{field}_confirmation`. So if you are trying to confirm the 'password' input it would be looking for a field named `password_confirmation`. So that input in the form needs to be changed to the name `password_confirmation`.

You won't need to compare the 2 password fields that are submitted since the `confirmed` rule has done that for you already (that is what it is for; to confirm that they match).

The Request class is not callable, `$request(...)`. That will throw an error since it isn't callable (there is no `__invoke` method defined on it to make it callable).

To create the User you can get the fields you need easily with the `only` method:

```
$request->only('name', 'email', 'password')
```

You can add your `is_admin` value to the array returned from the `only` call:

```
User::create($request->only('name', 'email', 'password') + ['is_admin' => true])
```

You will have to make sure that the `is_admin` field is "fillable" on the Model.

In general you don't need to be calling `request()` any where in this method since you have a Request instance injected as `$request` already.

Also, your form isn't handling a file upload so you don't need `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Comment: hello @lagbox, thank you for your help, it can running well now :)

Comment: Hello, when I used this``` User::create($request->only('name', 'email', 'password') + ['is_admin' => true]), ``` the password not be encrypted. 
I try to ```Hash::make('password')``` or ```bcrypt('password')``` but the value of password is not have default value,
I try ```Hash::make($request->password)``` but it is error .
 So, what shoul be change?

Comment: `$request->only('name', 'email') + ['is_admin' => true, 'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password'))]`